# Sum Column for Running Total where Overlapping Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with about 3 million rows of Customer Sales by Date.

For each CustomerID row I need to get the sum of the Spend_Value
WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN Order_Date_m365 AND Order_Date

Order_Date_m365 = OrderDate minus 365 days.

I just tried a self join but of course, this gave the wrong results due to rows overlapping dates.

If there is a way with Window Functions this would be ideal but I tried and can't do the between dates in the function, unless I missed a way.

Tonly way I can think now is to loop so process all rank 1 rows into a table, then rank 2 in a table, etc., but this will be really inefficient on 3 million rows.

Any ideas on how this is usually handled in SQL?

```sql
SELECT CustomerID,Order_Date_m365,Order_Date,Spend_Value
FROM   dbo.CustomerSales
```

[image]

Comment: I would ask if you actually need *all 3 million* rows in returned from your query alongside the fact that you want/need the `SUM` of their orders from the prior 365 days.

Comment: Hi Larnu, yes unfortunately I need it and on 365 days as it will then be fed into an analytic system where users can select any range of dates, it will be used to segment customer by High, Lapsing, InActive etc. and see the movement between orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions likely won't help you here, so you are going to need to reference the table again. I would suggest that you use an `APPLY` with a subquery to do this. Provided you have relevant indexes then this will likely be the more efficient approach:

```sql
SELECT CS.CustomerID,
       CS.Order_Date_m365,
       CS.Order_Date,
       CS.Spend_Value,
       o.output
FROM dbo.CustomerSales CS
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Spend_Value) AS output
                  FROM dbo.CustomerSales ca
                  WHERE ca.CustomerID = CS.CustomerID
                    AND ca.Order_Date >= CS.Order_Date_m365 --Or should this is >?
                    AND ca.Order_Date <= CS.Order_Date) o;
```

Comment: Ah of course Cross Apply Itzik Ben-Gan's favourite, didn't think of that. Great shout will give it a go.